# How to make a variable route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, routes

I am really struggling to make a route like

`localhost:3000/api/search/:{this_can_be_anything}`

I want to hit the `search` controller, and have the final thing be taken in as a variable

please let me know if you know how to do this

EDIT:
What I didn't mention (or realise would be important) is that `:{this_can_be_anything}` is actually going to reflect a url such as `david:office`  So, I want to be able to look up something like `localhost:3000/api/david:office` and see the related page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All controllers and get/post routes can take params. They are passed in the url like this:

```
localhost:3000/api/search?q=whatever_you_type_here
```

Inside your controller you'll have access to the params hash

```
params
=>{q: 'whatever_you_type_here'}
```

You can add more than one param like this:

```
localhost:3000/api/search?a=foo&b=bar
```

Now your controller search method will get params

```
params
=>{a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, This would work if there wasn't an additonal restriction on me:

EDIT:
What I didn't mention (or realise would be important) is that `:{this_can_be_anything}` is actually going to reflect a url such as `david:office`  So, I want to be able to look up something like `localhost:3000/api/david:office` and see the related page

Answer (score 2):

You're not far from the actual syntax. Something like this might meet the requirements.

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/api/search/:query', to: 'api/search#index'
```

```
# app/controllers/api/search_controller.rb
module Api
  class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
      query = params[:query]
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

The above should send the request `GET /api/search/david:office` to the `index` action of the `SearchController`. The string `"david:office"` will be avaible through the `:query` parameter.